# SSRS and Azure VM

Tags: azure, reporting-services

I have created a sql server instance on an Azure VM and uploaded my sql server backup and the various reports that were previously running on a local box. This has all gone well and I can connect to the database via management studio from my remote client.

I can also run all my reports locally on the Azure VM using RDP. They all work fine.

The problem comes when I try to connect to my report server using Internet Explorer from my remote client. All I get is Page is not found messages.

I have opened Port 80 on the Azure firewall and added an inbound rule in my Azure Portal to allow connection on Port 80.

I have tried using the Public DNS name I have created something like AFDSQL.NorthEurope.cloudapp.azure.com/Reports_MSSQLSERVER/Pages/Folder.aspx and also tried the IP address directly but neither work.

What am I missing?

Roy

Comment: Have you opened port 80 in the Windows firewall?

Comment: I'm in the same boat, I also tried binding the Web Service Url and Web Portal Url to the dns name as host header.  The urls look right http://blahblahblah.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com/reportserver but they aren't even browsable locally like the localhost urls were.

Answer (score 1):

Just got mine working!

Yes, you have to open port 80 on the windows firewall in your azure vm.

You also have to open the port in the network security section of your azure portal.

Finally the address to use is http://servername/reports/browse not reports/folder.aspx like you are used.